# Optimisation problem - derivatives

Tags: derivatives, optimization, logarithms

The intensity of the reaction to a certain drug, in appropriate units, is given by

$R(t)= 5te^{-0.5t} + \ln{2t} + 0.01 $

Where $t$ is time in Hours after the drug is administered .
What is the intensity of reaction after $\frac{1}{2}$ hour of administrating the drug ?

My understanding of the question is that I need to find the "gradient" at the point when $t = \frac{1}{2} $

I have found the

1st derivative -

$R'(t) = -2.5te^{-0.5t} + 5e^{-0.5t} + \frac{1}{t} $

What do I sub in for the $e$ ?

Comment: No need to find the gradient.  Just substitute $t=1/2$ (i.e., find $R(1/2)$).

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris then what do I do with the $e$ ?

Comment: $e$ is a constant ($e \approx 2.718$)

Comment: @user307640, Dando18 is correct.  $e$ is a constant and is approximately

$$e \approx 2.71828\ldots.$$

Comment: @user307640, if you want a more accurate computation, use a scientific calculator, or plug in your values into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

Answer (score 1):

If $R(t)$ gives the intensity at time $t$, then to find the intensity after $\frac{1}{2}$ hour(s) simply find $R(1/2)$ by substituting,

$$ R(1/2) = (5/2) e^{-0.25} + \ln 1 + 0.01 \approx 1.957 $$

In response to your question about $e$: Also called [Euler's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), $e$ is approximately $2.718$ and given by $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ or $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$.